# Any efficient way to generate Shapely polygons while excluding a set of points, and including a set of points?

Tags: polygon, shapely

I want to generate N polygons that should satisfy the following:

1. It must NOT include a set of points (at the maximum 50)
2. It MUST include a set of points (at the maximum 50)

My strategy is to create a polygon randomly and check if that polygon satisfy (1) and (2). Do the same for N=100 polygons. For adding 10 polygons, it takes about 1 min. This process is extremely time consuming. Is there any better way to handle it? My code is below:

Linux, Shapely version : 1.8.5.post1, Python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from shapely.geometry import box, Point
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely import affinity

def create_center_origin_rectangle(object_center, deg, object_length=0.06):
    # find bottom left corner coordinate from center
    object_x_corner = object_center[0] - (object_length)/2.0
    object_y_corner = object_center[1] - (object_length)/2.0

    # add rectangle patch using bottom coordinates
    rectangle = patches.Rectangle((object_x_corner, object_y_corner), object_length, object_length,linewidth=1, edgecolor='none', facecolor='none', alpha=0.5)

    # get bottom left and bottom right coordinates from Rectangle()
    bottom_left = rectangle.get_xy()
    upper_right = (rectangle.get_x()+rectangle.get_width(), rectangle.get_y()+rectangle.get_height())

    # use bottom left and bottom right coordinates to create Shapely box
    polygon_box = box(bottom_left[0], bottom_left[1], upper_right[0], upper_right[1])
    polygon = affinity.rotate(polygon_box, deg)
    patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, facecolor='none', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
    return patch, polygon

random.seed(100)
np.random.seed(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-0.1,0.1)
ax.set_ylim(-0.1,0.1)

outside_points = np.asarray([(0.01,0.05), (0.023,0.06), (-0.03, 0.02), (-0.04, -0.02), (-0.03,-0.03), (0.012, -0.03)])
ax.plot(outside_points[:,0], outside_points[:,1], marker='*', linestyle='', color='black', label='outside points')

inside_points = np.asarray([(0.02, 0.04), (0.03, 0.03), (0.02,0.06)])
ax.plot(inside_points[:,0], inside_points[:,1], marker='*', linestyle='', color='red', label='inside points')

num_cube = 0

print "start time:", datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')

while num_cube < 10:
    inside_points_check = []
    outside_points_check = []

    cube_center_x = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.06)
    cube_center_y = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.06)
    deg = np.random.randint(0,359)
    patch_1, polygon_1 = create_center_origin_rectangle(object_center=(cube_center_x, cube_center_y), deg=deg)

    # condition 1: check if polygon does not contain all the OUTSIDE points
    for outside_point in outside_points:
        outside_points_check.append(polygon_1.contains(Point(outside_point[0], outside_point[1])))

    # condition 2: check if polygon contains all the INSIDE points
    for inside_point in inside_points:
        inside_points_check.append(polygon_1.contains(Point(inside_point[0], inside_point[1])))
    
    # satisfy both condtion 1 and condition 2
    if np.all(np.asarray(outside_points_check) == False) and np.all(np.asarray(inside_points_check) == True):
        num_cube += 1
        ax.add_patch(patch_1)

print "end time:", datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it correct to interpret your problem statement to say that the N polygons collectively contain the desired points - i.e., the union of the N polygons contains all the desired points and excludes the undesired points? How big is N compared to the number of desired/undesired points?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. N: 30 to 50, undesired points: 10 to 20, and desired points:30 to 50

Comment: randomly searching for the right polygons is not going to work unless you get incredibly lucky. You will need to come up with a more coherent method that actually searches for separating boundaries. For example, you could sweep a line from left to right (west to east) until you find the first prohibited point. All the points to the left can be put in one polygon which you could generate as the convex hull of those points. You could then sweep past the prohibited point(s) until the next allowed point and generate a new group. You might alternate west-east, north-south sweeps.